# Javascript Radio add value Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any ways to set a textarea when I clicked a radio button at some row (`<tr>`) ?

```js
function changeTeks(i){
  var teks = '';
  var row = $(this).parents('tr');
  if(i == '1'){
    teks = row.find('input[name="brazil[]"]').val();
  }else if(i == '2'){
    teks = row.find('input[name="normal[]"]').val();
  }else if(i == '3'){
    teks = row.find('input[name="gagal[]"]').val();
  }else{
    teks = "belum";
  }
  row.find('textarea[name="hasil[]"]').text(teks);
  console.log(teks);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<input type='hidden' name='gagal[]' value='fail in test 1' />
<input type='hidden' name='normal[]' value='not yet in test 1 ' />
<input type='hidden' name='brazil[]' value='success in test 1' />
<td><input type='hidden' name='lingkup[]' value='30' />Test 1</td>
<td><input type='radio' name='target0[]' value='1' onclick='changeTeks(1)' />
</td>
<td><input type='radio' name='target0[]' value='2' onclick='changeTeks(2)' />
</td>
<td><input type='radio' name='target0[]' value='3' onclick='changeTeks(3)' />
</td>
<td><textarea name='hasil[]' class='form-control'></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<input type='hidden' name='gagal[]' value='fail in test 2' />
<input type='hidden' name='normal[]' value='not yet in test 2' />
<input type='hidden' name='brazil[]' value='success in test 2' />
<td><input type='hidden' name='lingkup[]' value='30' />Test 2</td>
<td><input type='radio' name='target1[]' value='1' onclick='changeTeks(1)' />
</td>
<td><input type='radio' name='target1[]' value='2' onclick='changeTeks(2)' />
</td>
<td><input type='radio' name='target1[]' value='3' onclick='changeTeks(3)' />
</td>
<td><textarea name='hasil[]' class='form-control'></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<input type='hidden' name='gagal[]' value='fail in test 3' />
<input type='hidden' name='normal[]' value='not yet in test 3' />
<input type='hidden' name='brazil[]' value='success in test 3' />
<td><input type='hidden' name='lingkup[]' value='30' />Test 3</td>
<td><input type='radio' name='target2[]' value='1' onclick='changeTeks(1)' />
</td>
<td><input type='radio' name='target2[]' value='2' onclick='changeTeks(2)' />
</td>
<td><input type='radio' name='target2[]' value='3' onclick='changeTeks(3)' />
</td>
<td><textarea name='hasil[]' class='form-control'></textarea></td>
</tr>
                                </table>
```

I always get `undefined` value from the parent. I want to fill `textarea` with text in `input type hidden value` for each row (because this hidden value is different for each row)

Comment: Inside the function `this` is not refer to the element, pass the reference as an argument

Comment: so I need to change `this` with?

Comment: `changeTeks(1)` ==> `changeTeks(1, this)` and `function changeTeks(i){
  var teks = '';
  var row = $(this).parents('tr');` ==> `function changeTeks(i, ele){
  var teks = '';
  var row = $(ele).parents('tr');`

Comment: `<input type='radio' name='target1[]' value='1' onclick='changeTeks(1, this)' />` ... `function changeTeks(i, el){}`

Comment: or simply bind the context and call it... `changeTeks.bind(this)(1)`

Comment: @PranavCBalan already change it, still undefined, updated snippet

Comment: @CrossVander : not a valid markup, move hidden field to any of the `td`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Trying answer below, now it works.. thanks for helping too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Pranav's comment pass `this` in your function and the use it inside.

```js
function changeTeks(ele,i){
   var teks = '';
   var row = $(ele).closest('tr');
   if(i == '1'){
     teks = row.find('input[name="brazil[]"]').val();
   }else if(i == '2'){
     teks = row.find('input[name="normal[]"]').val();
   }else if(i == '3'){
     teks = row.find('input[name="gagal[]"]').val();
   }else{
     teks = "belum";
   }
   row.find('textarea[name="hasil[]"]').html(teks);
   console.log(teks);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<input type='hidden' name='gagal[]' value='fail in test 1' />
<input type='hidden' name='normal[]' value='not yet in test 1 ' />
<input type='hidden' name='brazil[]' value='success in test 1' />
<td><input type='hidden' name='lingkup[]' value='30' />Test 1</td>
<td><input type='radio' name='target0[]' value='1' onclick='changeTeks(this,1)' />
</td>
<td><input type='radio' name='target0[]' value='2' onclick='changeTeks(this,2)' />
</td>
<td><input type='radio' name='target0[]' value='3' onclick='changeTeks(this,3)' />
</td>
<td><textarea name='hasil[]' class='form-control'></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<input type='hidden' name='gagal[]' value='fail in test 2' />
<input type='hidden' name='normal[]' value='not yet in test 2' />
<input type='hidden' name='brazil[]' value='success in test 2' />
<td><input type='hidden' name='lingkup[]' value='30' />Test 2</td>
<td><input type='radio' name='target1[]' value='1' onclick='changeTeks(this,1)' />
</td>
<td><input type='radio' name='target1[]' value='2' onclick='changeTeks(this,2)' />
</td>
<td><input type='radio' name='target1[]' value='3' onclick='changeTeks(this,3)' />
</td>
<td><textarea name='hasil[]' class='form-control'></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<input type='hidden' name='gagal[]' value='fail in test 3' />
<input type='hidden' name='normal[]' value='not yet in test 3' />
<input type='hidden' name='brazil[]' value='success in test 3' />
<td><input type='hidden' name='lingkup[]' value='30' />Test 3</td>
<td><input type='radio' name='target2[]' value='1' onclick='changeTeks(this,1)' />
</td>
<td><input type='radio' name='target2[]' value='2' onclick='changeTeks(this,2)' />
</td>
<td><input type='radio' name='target2[]' value='3' onclick='changeTeks(this,3)' />
</td>
<td><textarea name='hasil[]' class='form-control'></textarea></td>
</tr>
                                </table>
```